# Function Transformation Graph

Tags: functions

Consider a real function $g(t)$. Now consider another real function $f(t) = -t +3$ that transforms the domain of $g(t)$. Suppose I have the graph of $g(t)$ and I'm trying to plot the $g(f(t))$ graph by drawing. In order to get the correct graph,  I could think of $f(t) = -(t-3)$, in which case, to plot $g(f(t))$, I should first invert $g(t)$ with respect to the vertical axis and then shift $3$ units to the right.The problem is that I'm not seeing the intuition into inverting $t$ first, and then shifting the inverted graph by 3 units to the right. Why is thinking of shifting 3 units to the right first $(t-3)$ and then inverting the shifted graph $-(t-3)$, a wrong procedure? Why is thinking of inverting the domain $( -t )$ and then shifting the inverted graph 3 units to the left $( -t + 3 )$ a wrong procedure ?

I got the intuitive feeling for all transformations, both of domain and of the range.This one though, is where I fall into confusion.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Math.SE! Sorry there's been a little delay with answering your question.

A function is a sequence of operations. The composition $g(f(t))$ could be described as a sequence of the following operations:

> (a) Subtract $3$ from $t$; (b) Change the sign of the result; (c) Apply $g$.

Both of these are valid ways to think about what the composition does. When constructing a graph, we begin with $g$ (since this is what we have already), which is step (c) in either case. Since (c) is understood already, next thing is to understand what happens if we do *(b) and then (c)*. Notice that it would be **wrong** to think of "(a) and then (c)", because this is not the order in which things are done in the construction of $g(f(t))$.

So, this is how we are led to introduce "invert in vertical axis", step (b). Finally it is time to bring (a) into the fold, which adds the shift by 3 units to the right.

Although I don't want to contribute to confusion, it seems natural to mention that the same composition $g(f(t))$ can be also described as a different process:

> (a) Change the sign of $t$; (b) Add $3$ to $t$; (c) Apply $g$.

If you interpret these as manipulations on graph of $g$, it will be "shift the graph to the left (b); and then invert about vertical axis (a)." Sounds different, but gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Let me just illustrate Pavel's excellent answer with an example. To use a somewhat visually interesting example, suppose our function is
$$g(t)=2\sin(t)+t$$
which has the following graph from $t=-6$ to $t=6$:

[image]

If we think of $f(t)$ as first translating (i.e., "sliding") $t$ over by 3, then negating the result, the graph of $g$ applied to $f(t)$ as we make this transformation looks like this:

[image]

If instead we think of $f(t)$ as negating $t$, and then translating the result over by 3, the graph of $g$ applied to $f(t)$ as we make this transformation looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, we get the same result either way.